# How to decompose the sql%rowcount of MERGE statement

Tags: sql, oracle, rowcount, sql-merge

Is it possible to get number of rows inserted and updated separately in merge query?

`SQL%COUNT` gives total number of rows merged.

Answer (score 0):

With knowledge of total number of rows before and after `merge`, you can utilize this information in simple arithmetic computation:

```sql
                ┌───────────────┐
            ▲ ▲ │               │
            │ │ │               │
            │ │ │               │
            │ │ │               │
count_before│ │ │               │
            │ │ │               │
            │ │ │               │
            │ │ │UUUUUUUUUUUUUUU│ ▲                ▲
            │ │ │UUUUUUUUUUUUUUU│ │rows_updated    │
            ▼ │ │UUUUUUUUUUUUUUU│ ▼                │
              │ │IIIIIIIIIIIIIII│ ▲                │sql%rowcount
   count_after│ │IIIIIIIIIIIIIII│ │rows_inserted   │
              │ │IIIIIIIIIIIIIII│ │                │
              ▼ │IIIIIIIIIIIIIII│ ▼                ▼
                └───────────────┘

select count(*) into count_before from table_name;
merge into table_name ...;
rows_merged := sql%rowcount;
select count(*) into count_after from table_name;
rows_inserted := count_after - count_before;
rows_updated := rows_merged - rows_inserted;
```

(credit to: [asciiflow.com](https://asciiflow.com))

Comment: you cannot be sure that your merge statement is the only statement that runs on that table at that time, so [count(*) after - count(*) before] makes no sense, or I'm missing something?

Comment: @Oguen your point is valid, the solution in my answer is safe only if the script is the only script being run on the db. OP didn't describe his usecase so I had mine on my mind where ETL makes initial import and there is no threat of race condition. To be fair, I guess that if the hypothetical `sql%insertedcount` and `sql%updatedcount` attributes existed they would hardly be useful in heavily concurrent environment anyway.

Answer (score -2):

A solution could be that whenever you insert or update one row.. you insert a code in your table, for example:

```
code=1 --> if insert
code=2 --> if update
```

so use that condition in where clause when you need count

Answer (score -2):

add a delete_count = count_before - count_after. would change the result
for insert update counts if count_after is less than count_before.

case for counting deletes with merge condition seperate statement to know how many were deleted. sql%rowcount could do that.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).